# PHP function to encode & etc. characters to corresponding HTML entities

Tags: php, html, entity

Does anybody know of a PHP function to encode strings containing special characters like & etc. to strings containing corresponding HTML entities?

The purpose is to display string data on a webpage without causing XML parsing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 2):

please see [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)  function.

Cheers